# Cygwin puts space after every `fi`

Tags: terminal, fonts, cygwin

Cygwin inserts a space everywhere after a combination of letters "fi". It is only visually so, if you copy the text, this space disappears.

[image]

And here's the text I copied:

```
#
pidfile = /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.pid

# Options: dbfile
# Notes.: Set the file for the fail2ban persistent data to be stored.
#         A value of ":memory:" means database is only stored in memory
#         and data is lost when fail2ban is stopped.
#         A value of "None" disables the database.
# Values: [ None :memory: FILE ] Default: /var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3
dbfile = /var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3
```

Comment: Did you install/enable a font with ligatures (such as FiraCode)?

Comment: What editor did you type or paste this into? It appear to automatically insert ligatures.

Comment: I've `Menlo for Powerline`, 10pt

Comment: What terminal are you using? This doesn't involve zsh.

Comment: Looks like some versions of "Menlo for Powerline" have ligatures. Try one of the versions that doesn't, instead. Or some other truly monospaced font.

Comment: I think it is better to open a bug in mintty instead, and close the question: https://github.com/mintty/mintty/issues